# Reformatting SQL output

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have data that looks like this

```
Name  XX YY
alpha 10 77
beta  10 90
alpha 20 72
beta  20 91
alpha 30 75
beta  30 94
alpha 40 76
beta  40 95
```

If I use

```
select * from scores order by Name, XX
```

I will get

```
Name  XX YY
alpha 10 77
alpha 20 72
alpha 30 75
alpha 40 76
beta  10 90
beta  20 91
beta  30 94
beta  40 95
```

At the moment, I'm retrieving the data in this form and using some C coding to format it like

```
Name   xx=10  xx=20  xx=30  xx=40
alpha  77     72     75     76
beta   90     91     94     95
```

Assuming that there will always be entries for 10, 20, 30, 40 for every name, is something like this possible in SQL without creating a new table like in [SQL Reformatting table columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18060826/sql-reformatting-table-columns)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use PIVOT to get your desired results. Before using PIVOT, some customization required in your value in column XX so that the final column output can meet your expectation.

```
SELECT * FROM
(
SELECT Name,'XX='+CAST(XX AS VARCHAR) XX,YY 
FROM your_table
)AS P
PIVOT(
    SUM(YY)
    FOR XX IN ([XX=10],[XX=20],[XX=30],[XX=40])
) PP
```

Output-

```
Name    XX=10   XX=20   XX=30   XX=40
alpha   77      72      75      76
beta    90      91      94      95
```

The same output can be also achieved with this following query-

```
SELECT Name,
[10] AS [XX=10],
[20] AS [XX=20],
[30] AS [XX=30],
[40] AS [XX=40]
FROM
(
    SELECT Name, XX,YY 
    FROM your_table
)AS P
PIVOT(
    SUM(YY)
    FOR XX IN ([10],[20],[30],[40])
) PP
```

Comment: If the items are strings, what can I use as the aggregate function?  I tried agg_string but got an error saying that aggregates that returned nullables were not allowed.

Comment: Use MAX that case.

Answer (score 1):

You could use dynamic PIVOT to achieve the same result which would be more robust,

```
CREATE TABLE #table1 (Name varchar(100), XX INT, YY INT)

INSERT INTO #table1 VALUES
('alpha',10,77),
('beta',10,90),
('alpha',20,72),
('beta',20,91),
('alpha',30,75),
('beta',30,94),
('alpha',40,76),
('beta',40,95)

DECLARE @pvt NVARCHAR(MAX) = '';
DECLARE @dynamicCol NVARCHAR(MAX) = '';

SELECT @pvt +=  ', ' +QUOTENAME([XX]) FROM #table1 GROUP BY [XX];
SELECT @dynamicCol +=  ', ' +QUOTENAME([XX]) + ' AS ' + QUOTENAME('XX=' + CAST([XX] AS VARCHAR(25))) FROM #table1 GROUP BY [XX];
SET @pvt = STUFF(@pvt,1,1,'')
SET @dynamicCol = STUFF(@dynamicCol,1,1,'')

EXEC ('
SELECT [Name],' + @dynamicCol+'
FROM #table1 a
PIVOT 
(
  SUM([YY])
  FOR [XX] IN ('+ @pvt+')
) PIV');
```

The result is as below,

```
Name    XX=10   XX=20   XX=30   XX=40
alpha   77      72      75      76
beta    90      91      94      95
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution with case

```
SELECT Name
  ,SUM(CASE when XX = '10' then YY else 0 END) AS 'xx=10'
  ,SUM( CASE when XX = '20' then YY else 0 END) AS 'xx=20'
  ,SUM( CASE when XX = '30' then YY else 0 END) AS 'xx=30'
  ,SUM( CASE when XX = '40' then YY else 0 END) AS 'xx=40'
  FROM temp_0
  group by Name
```

Comment: As you group by Name, Distinct is not required I think.

Comment: @mkRabbani Yeah, you are right, I forgot to remove that.

Comment: Produces rows with lots of zeros.